# How to removeUnusedInfluences in pymel

Tags: python, maya, pymel

I can't seem to find the command in PyMEL.

How do you trigger the `removeUnusedInfluences` command on a mesh you have selected using PyMEL?

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to `eval`:

```
import pymel.core as pc
pc.mel.removeUnusedInfluences()
```

Answer (score 0):

removeUnusedInfluences is a mel script. To get it from Pymel use the **mel** object's eval method:

```
from pymel.all import mel
mel.eval("removeUnusedInfluences()")
```

more [here](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/PyMel/generated/classes/pymel.core.language/pymel.core.language.Mel.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was hoping there was a function for it within pymel for this but this will do the job just fine.

Comment: You can tell if a function is mel or part of the api by calling the mel help command on it - if it's a mel script rather than a builtin it will tell you where the file comes from.

Comment: @theodox i.e. with `whatIs`